# C++ equivalent of SDL style union based events

Tags: c++, c++11

I am running into a situation where I need to define a type "Requirement" where every type of requirement has to carry different data. Like:

Requirement1:

- type: BUILDING_AT
- data: building type, building location

Requirement2:

- type: WORKER_AT
- data: worker location

...

This is essentially the same problem that user events face. These are often implemented using a union encapsulating all possible data that is needed, with a single variable determining the type. [SDL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Unions#Example_in_Practice%3a_SDL_Events) and [SFML](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/Event.hpp) are both examples of this, and this is how I have implemented the requirements currently.

Despite this method working alright, I can't help but thinking that it seems somewhat unelegant in a modern C++ context. For one thing, it removes the default constructors and copy/move mechanisms, forcing me to redefine all of that. Another thing (albeit not an issue in practice) is that every instance takes as much memory as the biggest possible instance. I don't know, maybe I am being silly but I'm just thinking that maybe there is a more elegant solution to apply.

So, do any of you know if there is a better solution using the latest tricks of C++? Pre-C++11-compatibility is no issue.

Comment: Have you considered an object-oriented solution, with inheritance and virtual functions and stuff?

Comment: For those who eschew object-orientation, there is always `boost::variant`.

Comment: Note that union-based events which both SDL and SFML use is really the approach which the X window system did. Of course, because SFML and SDL are built over that, they just follow the same approach. The X documentation is very ilustrative, check it.

Comment: Type erasure?  Split the data between the type, and a distinct block with parameters?  Small string optimization, where small parameter bundles are inline?  Manual storage/polymorphic messages, where the size of your struct varies with subtype, precluding automatic storage?